# Menu Item won't turn active after adding NavigationItemSelectedListener

Tags: java, android, android-bottom-nav-view

I have a `BottomNavigationView`.

It works and shows the text title under the item that the user clicked.

However, adding a `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` stops the tapped item to show it's title underneath it's icon. It still gets the ripple effect and it runs any code attached to that item listener. Adding a Log.d() and printing a message to the console on item click shows that the listener runs. But for some reason the text title for that item won't show up under. So you don't know what button you last pressed.

I've tried moving it from onStart() to onCreate() but the same problem occurs.

Commenting it out fixes the problem, but I want to trigger events on the item clicks.

Listener

```
bnvMain.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.navigation_home:
                        // open fragment 1
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                        // open fragment 2
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                        // open fragment 3
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigation_profile:
                        // open fragment 4
                        Log.d("myTag", "This seems to be running...");
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

XML

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bnvMain"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/colorNavText"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. The solution is to change

```
return false;
```

to

```
return true;
```

My guess is it tells the Listener that a menu item wasn't clicked?